# Round float to floats in array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, floating-point, rounding

Let's say you have a float 5.9476386 and an NSArray with the floats 1,4,8,12,... stored in ascending order.

```
NSArray *centers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1],
                     [NSNumber numberWithDouble:4],
                     [NSNumber numberWithDouble:8],
                     [NSNumber numberWithDouble:12],
                     ...
                     nil];
```

I want a new float that rounds the number to the closest number in the array.
So in this case the new float wil be 4 because 4 is the closest of the numbers of the array to 5.9476386.

How can i do this? I'm working in Objective-C/Cocoa

Comment: That's nowhere near enough information. By "array", do you mean C arrays, or `NSArray`? Is the array sorted? Please edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array is sorted in ascending order

```
 for ( int j=0; j< [myArray count]; j++ ) {
     float current = [((NSNumber *)[myArray objectAtIndex: j ]) floatValue];
     if ( current > myFloatNumber ) {
         if ( j==0 ) { return current;}  // 

         float prev = [((NSNumber *)[myArray objectAtIndex: j-1 ]) floatValue];

         if ( fabs(prev-myFloatNumber) > fabs(current-myFloatNumber) ) {
            return current;
         } else {
            return prev;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I was wondering if ther was a simple solution. I think i will use this one. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

One O(N) solution (where N is the number of items in your array) is to loop through the array, calculating the distance d = |float - a[i]| for each item in the array a[i], and storing away the value a[i] when the distance is minimal.

Comment: Provided that the array is sorted, you can also apply binary search if the array could be large. And of course you should stop looking once you find the first value greater than your value (again, if the array is sorted).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the array is sorted — and only when it's sorted — you can use binary search, which is provided by the method `-indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` (assuming iOS ≥4.0):

```
// assume theArray is an NSArray of NSNumber sorted in ascending order.

double target = 5.9476386;

NSUInteger count = [theArray count];
NSNumber* targetNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:target];

NSUInteger index = [theArray indexOfObject:target
                             inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, count)
                                   options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
                           usingComparator:^(id x, id y) {
                                               return [(NSNumber*)x compare:y];
                                           }];
```

Since binary search only return the smallest number which is ≥ the target value 5.9476386, we have to compare it with the previous item in the array to see which one is actually closer:

```
// for simplicity, I assume the array has at least 1 object here.
NSNumber* before = [theArray indexOfObject:(index == 0 ? 0 : index-1)];
NSNumber* after = [theArray indexOfObject:(index == count ? count-1 : index)];
double absDiffBefore = fabs([before doubleValue] - target);
double absDiffAfter = fabs([before doubleValue] - target);
return absDiffBefore < absDiffAfter ? before : after;
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array and calculate the differences of your float to the floats and compare the absolute value of the results.